# Openlayers 3 Raster Image overlay

Tags: image, openlayers-3, raster

I have written this brief javascript code with openlayer 3.15.1 that loads a map with four layer: the first is base layer took from Openstreetmap, the second and third are vector layers and last one is a jpg image (Raster image) that I have on local storage.
Why I can't load the Raster Image????

```
var regStyle = new ol.style.Style ({

           fill: new ol.style.Fill({

            color: 'rgba(127,129,112,0.3)'


           }),
           stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({

            color: 'green', width: 2})                             
        });


var reg = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/Project_first/assets/geojson/regioni.geojson',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    projection: 'EPSG:3857' 
  }),

  style: regStyle
});




var prov = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/Project_first/assets/kml/province.kml',
    format: new ol.format.KML(),
    projection: 'EPSG:3857'

  })
});


  var base_layer = new ol.layer.Tile({

    source: new ol.source.OSM()
  }); 

  var italy = ol.proj.fromLonLat([14.334, 40.965])

  var view = new ol.View({

    center: italy,
    zoom: 6,
  });


var scale = new ol.control.ScaleLine({

  className: 'ol-scale-line',
  target: document.getElementById('scale-line')
});




  var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
        coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(2),
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        // comment the following two lines to have the mouse position
        // be placed within the map.
        className: 'custom-mouse-position',
        target: document.getElementById('mouse-position'),
        undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
      });







var raster=  new ol.layer.Image ({
        source: [
                 new ol.source.ImageStatic({

                     imageExtent: [0, 0, 1024, 968],
                     projection: new ol.proj.Projection ({
                         code: 'EPSG:3857'

                     }) ,
                     url: 'http://localhost:8080/Project_first/assets/img/allertaMeteo2.jpg',
                    })]
    });



  var scale = new ol.control.ScaleLine();

  var map = new ol.Map({

     controls: ol.control.defaults({
          attributionOptions: ({  collapsible: false })

           }).extend([mousePositionControl, scale]),

    target: 'map',
    layers: [base_layer, prov,reg, raster],
    view: view

  });





  function initMap()
{
    // do map object creation and initialization here
    // ...

    // add a click event handler to the map object
    GEvent.addListener(map, "click", function(overlay, latLng)
    {
        // display the lat/lng in your form's lat/lng fields
        document.getElementById("lat").value = latLng.lat();
        document.getElementById("lng").value = latLng.lng();
    });
}
```

Comment: You might have to set the image size - [check here](http://www.acuriousanimal.com/thebookofopenlayers3/chapter02_04_image_layer.html). [docs](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.0/apidoc/ol.source.ImageStatic.html) state, that it has to be set _if auto image-size-detection fails for some reason_.

Comment: And also - are you sure the img url is valid? (You probably are. just checking).

Comment: I try it but without result.....

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you've specified the image extent in pixels instead of the map projection units, which you specified as 3857 in the source of the static image.  It's probably possible to use all pixels here.  However, what I've done in our current project is to georeference the images in the EPSG 3857 projection and then specify the image extent in that coordinate system.  Code snippet on that:

```
source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
        url: "images/ndfd/conus/mercator/maxt_2016020200.png",
        imageSize: [3328, 2048],
        imageExtent: [-15028131.257, 1878516.407,-6887893.493, 6887893.493],
        projection: ovProj

    }),
```

The ovProj variable is set to the 3857 projection.  If you intend to keep pixels, recommend you check the Static Image example on the OpenLayers Examples page.